# Use microphone in webrtc & media recorder simultaneously in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc, mediarecorder, screen-recording

I am using webrtc for video calling in android. I am simultaneously screen recording after call is connected in sender end. I am getting this error log in sender end. Receiver end voice is not hearing when screen recording is started using MediaRecorder. I think webrtc is not streaming audio to receiver end when media recorder is started using microphone.

**Error**

```
AudioRecord: start() status -38
2020-06-25 13:37:18.948 3276-5257/com.obs.booking E/WebRtcAudioRecord: WebRtcAudioRecord: Start recording error: AUDIO_RECORD_START_STATE_MISMATCH. AudioRecord.startRecording failed - incorrect state :1
2020-06-25 13:37:18.949 3276-5257/com.obs.booking E/AudioRecordJni: StartRecording failed!
2020-06-25 13:37:18.949 3276-5257/com.obs.booking E/libjingle: (voe_base_impl.cc:439): StartSend: Failed to start recording
2020-06-25 13:37:18.949 3276-5257/com.obs.booking E/libjingle: (voe_base_impl.cc:386): StartSend() failed to start recording
2020-06-25 13:37:18.949 3276-5257/com.obs.booking E/libjingle: (audio_send_stream.cc:245): AudioSendStream::Start failed with error: -1
```

Help me out to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the audio recording is failed due to incorrect state.
This error "AUDIO_RECORD_START_STATE_MISMATCH" tells that when the start() methods is called the audio recording already is in progress.
It is possible there is a conflict between media-recording and WEBRTC audio recording.

To solve this there are several ways that I hope be useful:

1 - make sure the source of both are same.

2 - Try to stop webRTC before start the media-recorder